# JSON.parse does not convert Stringified JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

```js
[
  { comicid: "5f55e91271b808206c132d7c", purchasetype: "pb_single" }
]
```

Above is my JSON Array that is stringified,I tried to JSON.parse and other functions like iterating it in a for loop but the key values also got scrambled.

Is there any way or an npm method that could instantly output the retrieved variable?

```js
var cartItemFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartitem"));
if (cartItemFromLocalStorage != null) {
  console.log("It came defined");

  console.log("This is OG Array: " + cartItemFromLocalStorage);
  let cartItemObject = {
    //set object data
    comicid: this.state.comicId,
    purchasetype: this.state.purchaseType,
  };
  console.log(cartItemObject);
  cartItemFromLocalStorage.push(cartItemObject);
  localStorage.setItem("cartitem", result); //localstorage only supports strings
  toast.success("Item Added to cart");
}
```

I checked the consoles and the states are putting up the data correctly.

I'm an extreme beginner in react js, help is much appreciated

Comment: Your input does not look like JSON, JSON requires `"`s around keys

Comment: Paste that into a json validator like jsonlint.com and it will confirm to you it is invalid

Comment: What is `result` in the following line: `localStorage.setItem("cartitem", result);`?

Comment: I'm sorry, it had been showing ever since, the google console had been showing as an Object, not as the real object, I just found it out on the application tab. thank youu

Answer (score 1):

The "JSON" you have written is actually JavaScript, not JSON. To convert it JSON use the `JSON.stringify` function, like so

```
> JSON.stringify([
  { comicid: "5f55e91271b808206c132d7c", purchasetype: "pb_single" }
]);
'[{"comicid":"5f55e91271b808206c132d7c","purchasetype":"pb_single"}]'
```

and then replace the value in localStorage with it.

Even easier would be to type into the developer console

```js
localStorage.setItem("cartitem", JSON.stringify([
  { comicid: "5f55e91271b808206c132d7c", purchasetype: "pb_single" }
]));
```